# How I can Sort my code in c++ from highest?

Tags: c++

Hey the same like in tittle. I have a program in c++ language and I want to sort from highest frequency.

```
    int main()
{
    std::map<std::string,int> words;
    std::ifstream fin("potop.txt");

    std::string s;
    std::string empty ="";
    while((s=getNextToken(fin))!=empty )
            ++words[s];


    int a=0;
    for(std::map<std::string,int>::iterator iter = words.begin(); iter!=words.end()&&a<20; ++iter,++a)
        std::cout<<iter->first<<' '<<iter->second<<std::endl;
}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Comment: www.writemycodeforme.com

Answer (score 0):

Use a multimap to reverse the key/value pair:

```
std::multimap<int,std::string> sortedmm;
for(std::map<std::string,int>::iterator iter = words.begin(); iter != words.end(); iter++)
{
   sortedmm[iter->second] = iter->first;
}
```

Now iterate that (already sorted)

```
for(std::multimapmap<int,std::string>::iterator iter2 = sortedmm.rbegin(); iter != sortedmm.rend(); iter++)
   std::cout<<iter2->first<<' '<<iter2->second<<std::endl;
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the `sort` from `algorithms` with starting and ending addresses as `rbegin` & `rend`. It will sort it in the decreasing order

like,

```
sort(yourMap.rbegin(), yourMap.rend())
```

Comment: That won't work, `std::map.rbegin` doesn't return the required type (`random_access_iterator`)